# Why does the function CONVERT round the result?

Tags: sql-server

When I execute `GETDATE` in SQL Server, I get, for example:

```
2021-01-29 17:07:56.319
```

But when I put it in a `CONVERT` function, it round the result, like :

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2021-01-29 17:07:56.319', 121);
```

returns

```
'2021-01-29 17:07:56.320'
```

Why?

While

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime2, '2021-01-29 17:07:56.319');
```

returns the expected result:

```
'2021-01-29 17:07:56.319'
```

My SQL Server is 2017 (v14.0.1000).

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has nothing to do with `CONVERT`, and to do with your choice of data type. Per it's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> Accuracy: Rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds

If you want your value to be accurate to 1/1000 of a second, use a data type that can have that accuracy.

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(datetime2(3), '2021-01-29 17:07:56.319', 121);
```

*Side note: SQL Server version 14.0.1000(.169 I assume) is SQL Server 2017 **RTM**. You haven't updated your version of SQL Server for 4 years! Open up Windows Update and get that instance to supported version!*

Comment: The latest CU is available here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56128  But for SQL Server 2017 and later there are no service packs, only CUs.  And so the RTM version is always technically supported (although you'll be asked by support to update before they seriously investigate any issue).

Comment: True, but the OP's won't have had any of the security patches over the last year, and they aren't supported against those if they suffer them, @DavidBrowne-Microsoft .